# App crashing at launch on TestFlight release when added OpenSSL into the project

Tags: swift, openssl

When I added OpenSSL into the project it is crashing at launch on TestFlight not on development process, I can open the project on my device on development process, but when I sent to the TestFlight it is crashing at launch

Why this is happening, and how can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I found the problem, because I'm using ssl in my application, I have to uncheck Include bitcodes option when uploading to the AppStore